# Does Google App Engine support using Spring @Async?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, asynchronous

I have an `@Api` annotated Endpoint class in a Google App Engine project. I am trying to call from a method inside this endpoint, a method annotated with @Async (org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async). When I debug in the `SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` class, `handleUncaughtException` method:

```
@Override
public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
    if (logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
        logger.error(String.format("Unexpected error occurred invoking async " +
                "method '%s'.", method), ex);
    }
}
```

The `logger.isErrorEnabled()` returns false and the method `invoke` of `AsyncExecutionInterceptor` returns with null.
So, my question is, does GAE support using Spring's @Async functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gooogle AppEngine (Standard) will not support the Multiple Threads, It runs on Single Thread If you use @Async Annotation usually it will create another thread and execute and in case of AppEngine it will not create the thread and it will not execute.

If you want to use the threads in Google AppEngine you still can use the Flexible version of Google AppEngine. which more like computer engine so it don't have many restrictions.